# Posting to facebook PAGE wall with php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I am becoming really desperate with posting to facebook feature. I know that many of you have already posted some help answers to this issue up to this point, but reading them has not helped me, unfortunately.

Here's my testing php code which I've tried to run many times but no posts have emerged on the desired page wall.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <?php
   // print_r($_GET);
  include 'http://www.balabuska.cz/facebook.php'; 
  $token='AAAFVjwFqJTUBAEwKoPabwwqYIEBT...';

  // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).  
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                                'appId'  => '375547669128501',
                                'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
                                'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
                              )); 

    //$token is the access token from the URL above  
    $post = array('access_token' => $token, 'message' => 'new test post - ' . date('Y- m-d'));  

   $facebook->api('/142066152577391/feed','POST',$post);  
 ?>
```

Comment: What is your problem? You should **never** provide `secret` or `access_token` for your application, I suggest you reset 'em immediately (since history is accessible by anyone)...

Answer (score 1):

try using a try catch block when posting a message to see whats going on. I also agree with [Juicy Scripter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155033/juicy-scripter) that you should never include your `access_tokken` or `secret` in future questions here.
so an example of what im saying would be:

```
try {
    $post = $_POST['status'];
    $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/142066152577391/feed?access_token='.$tokken, 'post', array('message'=> $post));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not reveal your `appId` or `secret`. They ought to be kept secret. Furthermore, use Exception handling to detect the error http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php. Posting some debug information, such as output of Facebook API call would be helpful as well.

The bit where you are including remote code (`http://www.balabuska.cz/facebook.php`) is not right either. You are most likely including empty file. You most likely want to reference a file on your file-system. Make sure `error_display` is `on`.